# Oat flakes pancakes / Oat flake pancakes

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I know I can say

> pea soup
>
> chickpea salad

(the noun/secondary adjective/attributive noun is used in singular)

But I don't know if I shoud use

> Oat flakes pancakes

or

> Oat flake pancakes

Comment: It comes down to whether you'd use "flake pancakes" (without the "oat"), otherwise, "oat flakes" is the phrase used in its entirety as an adjective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use "Oat flake" (singular) as the adjective/attributive noun. When "Oat flakes" are the noun, then you choose between singular/plural. But generally, nouns used as adjectives will take a singular form.

Usages:
I fed him oat flakes (used as a noun, so plural)
I made him oat flake pancakes (used as an adjective, so singular)

*Edit*
You might use a plural form if the pancakes contained multiple types of oat flakes. But only if that distinction was important. Generally, you'd still tend toward the singular

Comment: Do you mean nouns used attributively? It's difficult to use a noun as an adjective.